# How do i delete a YouTube account or Google account and keep my purchases

Tags: android, youtube, gmail

So I got my first Android phone about 8 years ago and I created a Google account to buy apps and later use to comment on Youtube. now even tho I never personally attacked anyone or cyberbullied anyone. I did comment on videos saying certain things sucked or were stupid or gave my opinion on things which would start fights with people. I wasn't going thru a good time back then I had a lot of stress and I was depressed with graduating Highschool and not knowing what to do with my life along with other things. Now as of today I still own the account and as I bought a good number of apps with it I would always just use that account to buy things, but I no longer want to be tied to all these stupid things I've said on Youtube or Google+. Is there a way to delete my Youtube account? I never had a channel where I posted videos but can I delete the Youtube account part of my Google account so my Comments will be gone? I don't think you can but is there a way to transfer my purchased apps to another again or link an account to them, Google only introduced the family share thing after I bought the majority of my apps. Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not related with programming

Comment: i wish i could help here but this is an off topic question. Please choose a forum properly to ask your questions.

Comment: Ask to google How to delete youtube account. you'll get the answer!

Answer (score 0):

it's unfortunately not possible to transfer paid apps to a different Google account.
You can do this..
Go into your phone Menu -> Accounts -> Google -> choose the account -> and choose what you want to sync.  You can limit it to Account Data or even sync nothing.

Then, you can still get access to all your paid content and not have deal with all the other stuff that was on the account.  Purchases you make are still available.  It just won't automatically update anymore if you happen to still use that account on another device